# How should Models an ViewModels interact?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel

How does the interaction between Model and ViewModels should be?
Supposing I've a class named Customer with Id and Email properties, and another one CustomerModel with the very same properties.

This is the scenario:

I load a view based on that CustomerModel, this view has a form. As form is submitted, the CustomerModel is passed upon to the Action, let's say, Save. In the Save action should I create an instance of Customer and populate it property by property?

Example below:

```
ActionResult Save(CustomerModel cm)
{
   //validation goes here

   Customer c = new Customer();
   c.Id = cm.Id;
   c.Email = cm.Email;

   context.Entry<Customer>(c).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
   context.SaveChanges();

   //continue
  }
```

Given I read in an earlier post that I should avoid use model class for both purposes, data and view model, I ask:

**Is that correct way to implement it?**

Comment: Looks fine. I might separate out the logic (validation, saving stuff to the database) into functions for maintainability and use some dependency injection like Unity, but it looks pretty clean.

Comment: The `CustomerModel` is view model and `Customer` is model? What kind of *interaction* do you see between them?

Comment: Maybe interaction was a bad choice of words, but the idea, the doubt is pretty clear, no?

Comment: The ViewModel should only contain the data and behavior related to the View. Usually the best way to map a ViewModel to a DomainModel (and vice versa) is to use a third party mapping library such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig into that.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the interaction between Model and ViewModels should be?

The view models describe data to the view. It is for presentation logic and providing data to the view. The models are for describing data from your data source such as sql or a file.

Example of stuff in your view models:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsFoundingMember { get { return Id < 1000; } }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsABaggins { get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name) ? Name.EndsWith("Baggins") : false; } }
}
```

Example of stuff in your models

```
public class Customer
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

I would try grouping the logic into functions for maintainability.

Say:

```
ActionResult Save(CustomerModel cm)
{
   if(!ValidateCustomerModel(cm))
   {
        //Deal with invalid data
   }

   UpdateCustomer(cm);

   //continue
}

public bool ValidateCustomerModel(CustomerModel model)
{
    //Do stuff
    return true;
}

public void UpdateCustomer(CustomerModel model)
{
   Customer c = new Customer();
   c.Id = cm.Id;
   c.Email = cm.Email;

   context.Entry<Customer>(c).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

After you have all of your CRUD logic separated out you could make some classes for that logic and look into Unity, Ninject, or plain old constructor injection.

e.g. Constructor Injection

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICustomerDL _customerDL;
    public MyController(ICustomerDL customerDL)
    {
        _customerDL = customerDL;
    }

    //Load your implementation into the controller through the constructor
    public MyController() : this(new CustomerDL()) {}

    ActionResult Save(CustomerModel cm)
    {
       if(!ValidateCustomerModel(cm))
       {
            //Deal with invalid data
       }

       _customerDL.UpdateCustomer(cm);

       //continue
    }

    public bool ValidateCustomerModel(CustomerModel model)
    {
        //Do stuff
        return true;
    }
}

public interface ICustomerDL
{
    void UpdateCustomer(CustomerModel model);
}

public class CustomerDL : ICustomerDL
{
    public void UpdateCustomer(CustomerModel model)
    {
       Customer c = new Customer();
       c.Id = cm.Id;
       c.Email = cm.Email;

       context.Entry<Customer>(c).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
       context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The benefit is all of your logic will be clean and structured which will make Unit Testing and code maintenance a breeze.

Comment: That's all right to me. But core concern in here is the instantiation of Customer and fill out it's properties. From answers I got I think I'm in right path.

Comment: @user1916886 Yeah the view model is for describing data to the view while the model is for converting data from the data source (sql, file, etc...). You will end up with a modest amount of mapping logic between your view models and models (and you can look into `AutoMapper` for some of that)